# UISearchBar error after going backwards

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uisearchbar

I've created a UISearchBar that works the first time i go into the viewController, but when i go to the next viewcontroller via. the UITableView and press back and try to search again i get following error:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<phraseObject 0xa72d8c0> valueForUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key name.'
```

Here is the code:

```
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qualifiedName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict {
    if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"language"]) {
        thename = attributeDict[@"name"];
        theimage = attributeDict[@"image"];
        theId = attributeDict[@"id"];

        object = [finalObject new];
        theObject = [countryObject new];

        object.name = thename;
        object.image = theimage;
        object.soId = theId;

        theObject.name = thename;
        theObject.image = theimage;
        theObject.soId = theId;

        [finalArray addObject:object];
        [finalArray2 addObject:theObject];

    }
}

-(void) searchThroughdata {

    self.filteredArray = nil;

    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF.name contains [c] %@",self.searchBar.text];
    self.filteredArray = [[finalArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate] mutableCopy];

}

-(void)searchBar:(UISearchBar *)searchBar textDidChange:(NSString *)searchText {
    [self searchThroughdata];
}


- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

        self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"background.png"]];
   height = 30.0;
searchBar.barTintColor = [UIColor clearColor];

    self.tableViewData.sectionIndexTrackingBackgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor]; // background color while the index view is being touched
    if ([self.tableViewData respondsToSelector:@selector(sectionIndexBackgroundColor)]) {
        self.tableViewData.sectionIndexBackgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];   
    }
    tableViewData.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    tableViewData.opaque = NO;
    tableViewData.backgroundView = nil;

    NSString* path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource: @"lists" ofType: @"xml"];
    NSData* data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile: path];


    rows = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    finalArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    finalArray2 = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    NSXMLParser* parser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithData: data];

    [parser setDelegate:self];
    [parser parse];    

}
```

Comment: post code in `viewWillApear` and `viewDidApear`

Comment: I only have viewDidLoad. I have added it at the bottom

Comment: Only debug logs will help to solve problem..go through it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is at:

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF.name contains [c] %@",self.searchBar.text];
```

Compiler unable to find `SELF.name`.

Where you are searching?What is name of object key?

Comment: That just weird since it has no problem finding the SELF.name first time i search

Comment: hmmm...Answer is all about what your console error is. Check using debbuger step by step

Answer (score 0):

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[ valueForUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key name.'

It seems that only debug can help to solve this issue. You should try to set "Exception breakpoint" ON - it may help to find the problem in code by stoping your app where exception is raised.

[How to set exception breakpoint](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-breakpoint_navigator/articles/adding_an_exception_breakpoint.html)